# Why Matplotlib draws a straight line from last value to the x-axis in a loglog() plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use a loglog plot for my dataset, but I want my plot lines end at the last y-value for each set, but matplotlib completes the loglog plot to the x-axis with a straight line, see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HzSq.png).

But I want my plot to be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXduN.png), ending at the exact end values.

I have same array for x-axes, but 4 different y-values, so I plot my graph like this:

```
plt.loglog(x,y1,x,y2,x,y3,x,y4)
```

I create my y arrays from txt file like this:

```
with open(os.path.join(root,name),'r') as fin:
    y1 = []
    for q in fin:
        y1.append(float(q.split(' ')[1]))
```

How can I remove zero values from y1 array?

Values go like this:

```
1 0.535025
2 0.116237
4 0.0336809
8 0.00814949
16 0.00159025
32 0.000202602
64 1.00662e-05
128 7.68864e-08
256 0
512 0
1024 0
2048 0
4096 0
8192 0
16384 0
```

Comment: This happens when your last point is zero (which cannot be shown on a log scale). Just make sure not to plot `0`, then the line will end at the last point.

Comment: I added my method to create y-array, would you help me how I can remove the zeros?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I simply added following code to replace zero values with NaN values, so that loglog() plot won't use the NaN values:

```
for i in range(0,15):
    if y1[i] == 0:
        y1[i] = np.nan
```

Note: I have 15 values in y1 array, that's why my range is 0 to 15.

So problem is solved! I get my plots as I wanted.